# There's any way to debug a UnhandledPromiseRejectWarning on a NodeJS API built with Express Generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express-generator

In this scenario when I run the local API I receive a warning with a

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPIPE
>       at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:835:14) (node:7028) > UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Especifing that might be a JS promise without a catch() callback written correctly. I checked the whole API (Controllers, Models, even middlewares) and all the functions and promises return correctly. All the mongoDB deamons are working well but the API only responds to 404 statuses.

There's any way to debug the API without include any TDD or tests units?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: the mongod process hung up and was unable to run properly. I kill the process and start it again.

I suppose that the warning is caused by the Mongo internal process to start the service and persist. Now it works without any warning

Comment: You can catch unhanded rejections with process.on('unhandledRejection', callback) if the library throwing the rejection is using native promises. This might give more clues to what the error actually is. Likely you will need to post more code.